# How to optimize CTE in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, recursive-query

Below is my recursive query to get children and child of each children but it takes too long to execute. How can I optimize this query so that it can execute faster. If I remove distinct, it brings multiple records.

```
        DECLARE @int_UserID INT
    DECLARE @ProjectID INT
    SET @int_UserID=74
    SET @ProjectID=96


    ;WITH Records AS (
            SELECT pu.int_USER_ID,alh.int_Level_ID 
            FROM tbl_PROJECT_USER pu INNER JOIN tbl_Project_User_Role pur ON pu.int_USER_ROLE =     pur.int_Project_User_Role_ID
            INNER JOIN tbl_Access_Level_Hierarchy alh ON   pur.int_Access_Level_IDRef=alh.int_Level_ID
            INNER JOIN tbl_USER u ON u.int_USER_ID=pu.int_USER_ID
            WHERE pu.int_USER_ID=@int_UserID AND pu.int_PROJECT_ID=@ProjectID

            UNION ALL
            SELECT pu.int_USER_ID,alh.int_Level_ID 
            FROM tbl_PROJECT_USER pu INNER JOIN tbl_Project_User_Role pur ON pu.int_USER_ROLE =    pur.int_Project_User_Role_ID
            INNER JOIN tbl_Access_Level_Hierarchy alh ON pur.int_Access_Level_IDRef=alh.int_Level_ID
            INNER JOIN Records R ON R.int_Level_ID=alh.int_Level_Order 
            WHERE pu.int_PROJECT_ID=@ProjectID 
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Records
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Thanks to all.
By changing the some logic, I got the optimum solution.

Comment: The most important thing when optimizing recursive CTEs is to ensure that the recursive part is optimized as this runs multiple times. Can you show us the execution plan?

Comment: Could you give an example of schema and dataset, please.

Comment: Now I got the optimum solution..

Comment: You need to find a way to take JOINs out of recursion... If tables are not too large, then use temporaty tables #MyTable to prepare data. Make sure you have indexes on columns used in JOINs.